# iOS: custom view in "viewForHeaderInSection:" delegate method hides for section = 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have some problem with `UITableView`, with it's Header. I need to set custom `UIView` in every section header, but the problem is in displaying header in section with number 0.

On the picture I tried to show my problem - on the left side its design what I need to do and on the right side it's what I did. [This is the comparison of screens](http://radikal.ua/data/upload/05615/6895e/78a480c279.jpg)

I need fully displaying of badge with character in any section.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could set transparent `tableHeaderView` to your `tableView` with the height that is being hidden. Like this:

```
UIView *tView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, DESIRED_HEIGHT)]; 
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tView;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm not saying that this is the only way to achieve what you want, this is the one the ways.

Answer (score 0):

Well its very simple solution. Just create your custom `UITableviewCell` class with manually nib file inside that drag and drop `UITableviewCell` and then  set imageview, label etc. On `UITableviewCell` and then just load the same inside your `viewForHeaderinsection`. As we know this method returns view. So when load custom `UITableviewCell` class inside this method just return cell, as it is also inherited from `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

make a custom header like this

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *viewHeader = [UIView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 28)];
UILabel *lblTitle = [UILabel.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 3, 136, 21)];
[lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13]];
[lblTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[lblTitle setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[lblTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[viewHeader addSubview:lblTitle];
return viewHeader;
}
```

Make a NSArray for Header Titles. and get this title in above method

Comment: Can you please format your code properly. This is an unreadable mess.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be an iOS7 specific issue with the tableView hiding partially behind the navigation bar? Have you tried running it on iOS6? I would *guess* that you wouldn't have the same issue. Try adding the following code to your table view file and see if it helps:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // if this is ios7 this code will make the view appear properly below the navigation bar
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
    }
}
```